# Eclipse plug-in where to create resources ans dispose them

Tags: eclipse, resources, rcp

General question when developing a eclipse plugin which is exported as a product and deployable plug-in (jar).
Where is the best place to create resources (Colors etc.) and dispose them? Tried it in the `start()` of the `Activator` class. Problem is i cant get the `Display` object there.

Also tried it in `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`where i can Access the Display via `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()`. This class gets only called when the plug-in is exported as a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For colors and fonts you can use the 'org.eclipse.ui.themes' extension point. Eclipse will then manage these resources for you. This also allows the user to customize the values in 'Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts'.

To get a colors and fonts defined using the extension point use:

```java
ITheme theme = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager().getCurrentTheme();

Color color = theme.getColorRegistry().get("color id");

Font font = theme.getFontRegistry().get("font id");
```